# R Kernel in Jupyter is using wrong directory

Tags: r, directory, anaconda, jupyter, jupyter-irkernel

Once upon a time ago, I installed the conda suite in Dropbox but then Dropbox did me dirty so I installed it in a different directory.  Deleted everything and started new but somehow R is being called from the old directory.

**What is calling the wrong `R` directory so I can go in and change it?**

My current R is:

```
$ which R
/Users/Mu/Sync/anaconda/bin/R
```

This is my error when I try to run an R kernel

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Mu/Sync/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/base/handlers.py", line 458, in wrapper
    result = yield gen.maybe_future(method(self, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/Mu/Sync/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1008, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Users/Mu/Sync/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 232, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
  File "/Users/Mu/Sync/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1014, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/Mu/Sync/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/handlers.py", line 58, in post
    sm.create_session(path=path, kernel_name=kernel_name))
  File "/Users/Mu/Sync/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1008, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Users/Mu/Sync/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 232, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
  File "/Users/Mu/Sync/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1014, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/Mu/Sync/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 73, in create_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "/Users/Mu/Sync/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1008, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Users/Mu/Sync/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 232, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
  File "/Users/Mu/Sync/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 282, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/Users/Mu/Sync/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py", line 87, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/Mu/Sync/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyter_client/multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/Mu/Sync/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 243, in start_kernel
    **kw)
  File "/Users/Mu/Sync/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 189, in _launch_kernel
    return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "/Users/Mu/Sync/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyter_client/launcher.py", line 123, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Mu/Sync/anaconda/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 950, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Users/Mu/Sync/anaconda/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1544, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/Mu/Dropbox/anaconda/lib/R/bin/R'
```

Comment: Says file not found for  '/Users/Mu/Dropbox/anaconda/lib/R/bin/R'. Where is the surprise in that? I would think we would need to know _exactly_ "how" you "tried to run an R kernel". That's kind of a strange place to put R. You may need to tell us how and what version was used when you installed R as well.

Comment: I know, it's looking for it in the wrong directory but I don't know what script is calling that path so I can change it to the right directory . I'm not saying the surprise is that it's not running, the surprise is that it's using the wrong directory and I don't know why it's getting directed there

Comment: What's in "/Users/Mu/Sync/anaconda/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py" or "/Users/Mu/Sync/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyter_client/launcher.py"?

Comment: And this link http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html shows how to inspect the "conda" environment variables.

Comment: I've been going through the files and can't find that path anywehere . I think it has to do with `self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run `R` and use this command `IRkernel::installspec()`

Comment: Thanks a ton for this answer! I was struggling with the same problem and this solved it in no-time.

Answer (score 1):

Specify it directly:

```
installspec(user = FALSE, rprofile = "/usr/local/bin/R")
```